# Trouble restoring an iPod touch backup

Tags: backup, itunes, ipod-touch, restore

I ran into some problems with my iPod, and am trying to restore a backup following this link -> http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414

I tried following the section under "Restoring your iPhone or iPod touch". When it gets to step 9, it simply doesn't show up - the restore happens, the iPod restarts, but I DO NOT get an option to set it up as a new device, or restore a backup. A backup does exist (checked the location).

Any ideas on how I can restore the backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might sound lame, but closing iTunes and restarting it seemed to work - after closing and restarting iTunes, and then replugging the iPod, I got the restore backup option. YAY!

Answer (score 0):

hold down the home button for 30 seconds, until it shows an itunes symbol on the ipod. If that doesn't work, hold down the home and power button for 30 seconds, until it shows an itunes symbol on the ipod. Then plug it into itunes.